# Редактировать колекцию продуктов в Magento

Tags: php, изображения, magento

У меня есть функция которая грузится при загрузке списка продуктов в магазине (событие 'catalog_block_product_list_collection'). Также написал функцию которая создает картинку в нужном месте и меняет даные в колекции. Но выводиться стандартная картинка magento product, все пути коректные. Как мне заменить вывод картинки продукта?

```
public function addLabel($collection)
{ 
    $event = $collection->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $label = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->load(13)->getData();
    $img = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $label['product_page_image'];
    foreach ($event as $product) {
        $product->getCollection();
        $imageUrl = $product->getSmallImageUrl();
        $a = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUrl);
        $b = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
        imagecopy($a, $b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40);
        $path = preg_replace('/^((https?|ftp):\/\/)?([a-z0-9_-])((\.[a-z0-9-])|([a-z0-9-]))*\.([a-z]{2,6})(\/?)/', '', $imageUrl);
        $path = preg_replace('/^((https?|ftp):\/\/)?([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/', '', $imageUrl);
        $path = preg_replace('/\.\w+$/', '', $path);
        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir() . $path;
        imagejpeg($a, $dir .'/water.jpg');
        chmod($dir .DS.'water.jpg', 0777);
        $product->setData('small_image', '/i/m/img-label_2/water.jpg'); 

    }   
    return $collection->getEvent()->setCollection($event);
}
```

Comment: чем ненравиться сделать это через админку/

Comment: Нужно программным кодом, просто так не спросил же.

Comment: но зачем какая задача стоит?

Comment: Нужно вывести картинку с лейблом(watermark)